# Trying to add custom fields to users in Django

Tags: python, django

I am fairly new to django and was it was going well until this.

i'm trying to add fields 'address' and 'phone_number' to users (create custom user basically) but i keep getting this error like this...

```
File "C:\Users\will5\Desktop\City\city_info\forms.py", line 5, in <module>
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
File "C:\Users\will5\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
packages\django\forms\models.py", line 257, in __new__
raise FieldError(message)
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (phone_number, address) 
specified for User
```

## this is models

```
...
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    phone_number = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=150)
...
```

## this is in my forms

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'email', 'password', 'address', 'phone_number']
```

I also read that in order to fix this problem i will have to restart my project by creating the custom user and migrating and i don't wanna do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are still importing the built in user model

You can fix it by replacing

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

with

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()
```

This assumes that you have set `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'yourapp.User'` in your settings.

As you have read in the docs, it is extremely difficult to switch to a custom user model after the project has started, there isn't an easy solution to this. If you can't restart your project, perhaps you could create a `Profile` model with a `OneToOneField` to the default `User` instead.

Comment: so in order to restart the project just adding the "class User" first and migrating, and thanks for the help by the way